# MySQL - Count how many "items" of one user changed since last login

Tags: mysql, sql, select

### I have the following tables:

Table **reviews**:
(Note: The modified = 00:00:00 is because it used to be a date, now it's a mysql datetime object) ([Original Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gtmIQ.png))):

```
+ -- + ------------- + ---------- + ------ + ------ +
| id | code_reviewer | modified   | course | review |
+ -- + ------------- + ---------- + ------ + ------ +
| 10 | 11            | null       | 1      | ....   |
| 10 | 12            | null       | 1      | ....   |
| 10 | 13            | null       | 1      | ....   |
| 11 | 12            | null       | 1      | ....   |
| 11 | 13            | null       | 1      | ....   |
| 11 | 14            | null       | 1      | ....   |
| 12 | 10            | 2017-03-31 | 1      | ....   |
| 12 | 11            | null       | 1      | ....   |
| 12 | 14            | null       | 1      | ....   |
| 13 | 10            | null       | 1      | ....   |
| 13 | 12            | null       | 1      | ....   |
| 13 | 14            | null       | 1      | ....   |
| 14 | 10            | 2017-03-31 | 1      | ....   |
| 14 | 11            | null       | 1      | ....   |
| 14 | 13            | null       | 1      | ....   |
+ -- + ------------- + ---------- + ------ + ------ +
```

Table **users**: ([Original Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qfoE5.png))):

```
+ -- + ------------------- + ------- +
| id | last_login          | name    |
+ -- + ------------------- + ------- +
| 3  | 2017-03-31 18:06:11 | Jan     |
| 10 | 2017-03-31 18:22:12 | Mama    |
| 11 | 2017-03-31 22:00:55 | Roman   |
| 12 | 2017-03-31 18:06:01 | Bubi    |
| 13 | 0000-00-00 00:00:00 | Oscar   |
| 14 | 0000-00-00 00:00:00 | Vincent |
+ -- + ------------------- + ------- +
```

This basically is *a review system*, so that one user can write 3 reviews for another user. These reviews are stored as JSON strings in `"reviews"."review"`. The column `"reviews"."code_reviewer"` says who writes a review and `"reviews"."id"` says who will get a review by the `code_reviewer`.

The `users.last_login` row and `reviews.modified` get updated as soon as an user logs in / a review gets updated.

## **What I want to select:**

I basically want to get, *how many reviews for a certain user changed since he last loged in*. So, it'll select anything between the `NOW()` and `user.last_login` date, and only these rows, *in which the `reviews.id` is equal to the user (`users.id`)*. This will be used for a kind of "badge feature"

**A good answer should contain two versions of the query:
    * One just as described above, so ALL THE REVIEWS of the user between the certain amuunt of time
    * Another which *only returns the reviews the user got in the interval FOR ONE COURSE (the course is an int field)*. Example: I want all reviews for user Jan (id=1) from the course 1 which got updated between 2017-03-31:18:06:11 (`users.last_login`) and `NOW()`.

Thanks in advance,
Jan!

Comment: Say a user has no such reviews at all. Should he/she be in the result (with count = 0) or not?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Yes he should. But just for confirmation: I only want the reviews [...] for ONE user. If he wasn't in the result, the result would be empty

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood correctly, this should be what you are looking for

```
select count(*) 
from users u
left join reviews r
on u.id =r.id
where r.modified > u.last_login and u.id = x
```

Comment: I think you're getting close to it, but if I run it with "id = 12" on the table described above it returns `count(*): 0`

Comment: And you want it to be `null` instead?

Comment: Sorry, I tried it on a wrong table setup. This answer is perfect. Thank you!

There's one last thing: How can I do this only for the reviews in `course` 1 or 2 etc? Something like `where r.course = Y` or so?

Comment: Yes, you only have to add a condition like that in the `where`